# Chromecast app not connecting on first try

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I work on a Chromecast app that has been out on the market for a little while. We started to receive reports that people cannot connect to the Chromecast on the first try after it has been booted up. We could not reproduce this until recently (and only one device happens to exhibit this behavior)

The Chromecast icon appears that it is connected, but the app never launches. Eventually the Chromecast icon shows that it is disconnected. I grabbed a logcat from this device.

```
D/CastSocket( 1037): [MiniDeviceController-1] onWritable when state is 1
D/CastSocket( 1037): [MiniDeviceController-1] SSLException encountered. Tearing down the socket.
D/CastSocket( 1037): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Error occured in delegated task:javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.HandshakeProtocol.fatalAlert(HandshakeProtocol.java:316)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.HandshakeProtocol.wrap(HandshakeProtocol.java:268)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:693)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:438)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at beb.k(SourceFile:671)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at bef.run(SourceFile:96)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
D/CastSocket( 1037): Caused by: com.android.org.conscrypt.AlertException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.HandshakeProtocol.fatalAlert(HandshakeProtocol.java:316)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ClientHandshakeImpl.verifyServerCert(ClientHandshakeImpl.java:559)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ClientHandshakeImpl.processServerHelloDone(ClientHandshakeImpl.java:373)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ClientHandshakeImpl$1.run(ClientHandshakeImpl.java:283)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.DelegatedTask.run(DelegatedTask.java:36)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at beb.a(SourceFile:721)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at beb.j(SourceFile:635)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    ... 2 more
D/CastSocket( 1037): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
D/CastSocket( 1037):    ... 9 more
D/CastSocket( 1037): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateNotYetValidException
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.checkValidity(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:216)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate.checkValidity(OpenSSLX509Certificate.java:209)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at bdu.checkServerTrusted(SourceFile:47)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ClientHandshakeImpl.verifyServerCert(ClientHandshakeImpl.java:556)
D/CastSocket( 1037):    ... 7 more
D/CastSocketMultiplexer( 1037): *** removing socket CastSocket:MiniDeviceController-1 (onWritable)
D/CastSocket( 1037): [MiniDeviceController-1] doTeardown with reason=4
D/DeviceFilter( 1037): DEACTIVATE MiniDeviceController-1; finished=false
D/DeviceFilter( 1037): socket is disconnected
D/CastMediaRouteProvider( 1037): onDeviceFilterError for 516b4a3a710d7bdfe8dc75ff4c4901a0: connection failed: error=4
```

This appears to be all in the Chromecast API in Google Play Services. We use Amazon S3 to host and use their SSL certificate. It seems odd that after this initial error, the devices do connect. I haven't been able to wrap my brain around this one. Our app is only available on Android devices, and not all devices exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Can you catch the exception and retry? The 2nd request should b OK

Comment: When you call connect, do you receive onConnected() callback? There shouldn't be any need to catch an exception in the app and try again.

Comment: I need to track down the device that is presenting with the error and debug whether I'm getting the onConnected() callback. I will update after I test that.

Comment: Just remember that until you receive onConnected, you should not try to launch your app

Comment: We don't try to launch the app until we receive the onConnected callback.

Answer (score 0):

The "CertificateNotYetValidException" exception usually happens when the client's clock is off. Perhaps the users that encountered this issue have their current date set in the past. You can reproduce this by changing your device's current date to be in the past.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the Chromecasts could not be seen when the time was 2 hours off. It did not reproduce the issue that I described.